# some unicode characters such as "⊆" occupy 3 lines in emacs 24.4.1 on ubuntu gnome 15.04 64bit

Tags: fonts, rendering, ubuntu

Not every unicode character occupies 3 lines, but '⊆', '∈', and other unicode mathematical symbols occupy 3 lines in emacs on my system.

How can I fix this rendering bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the answer is: *try another font*.

There was quite a lot of discussion about this problem recently in the thread for [bug #20628](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=20628) of the Emacs bug list.

You will even see some info about particular fonts there, which might be helpful for your particular question. Oh, and note that there were some changes made to how Emacs picks a font, as an attempt to deal with this problem. These fixes are planned to be merged into the Emacs development trunk soon.

Comment: http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=20628#56 works around the bug, but I'll have to wait for a new version of emacs to be available on ubuntu and fix the bug permanently.

Answer (score 2):

Try a different font. It works for me in DejaVu Mono but doesn't in some others.